# Students confusing "object types" in introductory proofs class

Tags: proofs, students-mistakes

In my intro to proofs (and discrete mathematics) class, I see a common mistake where students make nonsensical statements because, for lack of a better term, they confuse the types of the mathematical objects they work with. Some examples:

- In a proof that a function $f: A \to B$ is onto, a student will say "Let $x \in f$" instead of "Let $x \in B$". Thinking of sets and functions as distinct objects would make a student realize this is not what they meant (we technically define a function as a set, but this is not what students are thinking of)
- When learning induction, students often define a predicate as being equal to an expression, such as $P(x) := 2^x + 5$, when thinking of expressions and predicates as distinct types would catch this error.
- In relations, students often say: "The pairs $(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)$ are reflexive" when we define reflexive as a property of a relation, not a property of individual elements.

My questions are:

1. Is there an established name for this type of error other than "type disagreement", and
2. How do you steer students from this type of mistake, and teach them to think about the "types" of the objects they work with?

Comment: I don't know of a name for this, but it's definitely less problematic then what one might call ["not even wrong"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong), and is more along the lines of a naive [category mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake).

Comment: As far as "2", you need to do Aristotelian imitation and practice (yes even of the object type recognition).  Sure, explain what they did wrong, BUT have them correct it, give them another problem.  Again and again.  We are more like dogs than like programmable computers.  We have aspects of each of course, but people here (especially from CS or proofy math types) routinely underestimate the human element of pedagogy thinking that proof or "magic explanation" will correct poor performance.  And this goes double if you have weak students!

Comment: I missed this before, but item 5 here is related: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17900/taxonomy-of-bad-proofs?rq=1

Comment: How should the predicate definition be written instead?

Comment: Frankly, all typing errors clearly indicate that the students were not taught proper logical reasoning. You may be interested in [what I wrote about this before (and its linked posts](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/24386/1550).

Comment: @user20820: Hello, user with almost the same id! Technically, Daniel is incorrect about this point. Predicates are **not** objects and actually **cannot be** objects in some foundational systems. They are meta-objects. To truly understand what defining a predicate means, you need to have a solid grasp of basic FOL (e.g. using a Fitch-style system such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820)), and you need to know the distinction between ∃elim and definitorial expansion for new predicate/function-symbols.

Comment: If you follow the definitorial expansion rule in that linked system, an example would be "Let Q(k) ≡ ¬∃x∈ℤ ( 2^k+5 = 17·x ), for each k∈ℕ.". This is a complete definition of a (fresh) predicate-symbol "Q" (where ℕ,ℤ,+,·,^ are inbuilt or have been defined). You can also see that if you fastidiously follow the rules in that system, you are forced to think about what every object type is, and will never write the kind of nonsense listed in this question.

Comment: @user20820 This usually happens in the context of an induction problem, where students are asked to prove some equation holds for all x, say the equation 1 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2. The predicate P(n), as we define it, should be the statement that the equation holds for some value of n. Students often misdefine it as saying P(n) = LHS or RHS.

Comment: @user21820 I don't have much background in formal logic, and we teach a predicate roughly as a "statement that takes an input variable, and is a proposition when that input is specified". I know this is a gross oversimplification, but I'm hoping it is not a harmful one.

Comment: I don't think the *error* is the same. if you say functions and sets are different the first student will just write "Let $x \in \textrm{the set of }f$" and nothing really changes.

Comment: The last one makes quite intuitive sense - why *shouldn't* a member of a relation, that maps an object to itself, be called a reflexive member of that relation? The error there is nothing more than imprecise use of language - the word "reflexive" could easily be defined that way, even though in your class it isn't - a bit like calling 2+4i an even number.

Comment: in the second one, what formula would a student then write that included P(x) and how would they understand that formula? if they write "$P(x)=37$; solve for $x$" there is actually no problem apart from you assuming that a function called $P$ is actually a predicate. If they write "$P(x) \lor Q(x)$" then I am very curious to know what the student thinks that means.

Comment: @user253751 I think you are suggesting in your first comment that students are just skipping a typecast or confusing notation, and I agree that a student who understood the concepts could make all the arguments you say. My point is a student taking an element of $f$ is usually making an error (they mean to take an element of the codomain). Thinking of a function and set as distinct objects (and not castable) would catch this mistake.
Students do often say something like "P(x) = 37. We prove P(x) is true for all x".

Comment: @Daniel In my first comment I suggest that resolving the type thing won't actually solve the issue. You will say "$f$ isn't a set", the student will correct themselves by saying "oh I meant the set of $f$" but it will still be wrong *and* what will be learnt isn't "I meant the range of $f$" but rather "Daniel is picky about 'type casts'".

Comment: The term 'typecast' comes from programming so a programming example: writing `printf("%d", (int)"hello world");` to make the compiler stop warning you that you used %d to print a string. It's wrong, but it did make the compiler shut up! Compiler: "%d is for ints" Novice programmer: "okay well make it an int then. Silly compiler, why didn't you do that for me..."

Comment: @Daniel: Your simplification is a bit off. Whether it's harmful or not I can't tell, but I know from experience that the only way to truly impart understanding (which does *not* require knowledge of formal logic) is to be 100% precise. You must clearly distinguish between predicates and predicate-symbols (which you didn't). Taking my earlier example, "¬∃x∈ℤ ( 2^[1]+5 = 17·x )" (where the "[1]" is a place-holder for the 1st input parameter) is a predicate. ", whereas the symbol "Q" in "Let Q(k) ≡ ¬∃x∈ℤ ( 2^k+5 = 17·x ), for each k∈ℕ." is a predicate-symbol.

Comment: Have you looked at the linked Fitch-style system I gave you? It links to [this post explaning why we want definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399880/21820). This motivation tells us that we want to be able to express **predicates** without having to write it again and again. To support this, we allow defining new **predicate-symbols**. Make very clear to students this motivation as well as the fact that "Q(E)" can be substituted for the definition of Q with every "[1]" replaced by "E". This is the **true meaning of definitions**.

Comment: I wish to emphasize that although you don't need to know formal logic (as found in textbooks on logic), you do need to teach a formal deductive system (like the one I gave you) otherwise it's nearly impossible to impart a fully precise ability to perform logical reasoning to students. The terminology doesn't matter, but the concepts and the system as a conceptual whole do. (In my above comment I made a typo; it should read "*is a predicate, whereas the symbol*". Too late to edit, sorry about that.)

Comment: From a philosophical background I would call this a [**category error**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake) (or category mistake), and hence I think some logicians would do the same.

Comment: Predicates *are* functions. They are just functions with a specific codomain. Thinking of them as an entirely different category is what leads to silliness like writing `if (condition) then return true else return false` instead of just `return (condition)` in programming.

Comment: You actually made the error yourself in your second example. P is a predicate. P(x) is an expression. If someone writes $P(x) := 2^x+5$, they are defining an expression in terms of another expression (although, if $P(x)$ is an expression representing a boolean, then they are still making a type error).

Comment: @user253751 "why shouldn't a member of a relation, that maps an object to itself, be called a reflexive member of that relation?" first of all, it doesn't "map" anything. It's a pair of numbers. Second, the OP already answered your question: "reflexive" is a property of relations, not of pairs. "the word "reflexive" could easily be defined that way, even though in your class it isn't" It's not clear what your point is. All definitions are arbitrary. That doesn't mean that there's no such thing as having a wrong one, or that wrong ones can imply misapprehensions.

Comment: @Acccumulation you create the same semantic argument again. Why *shouldn't* a pair (x,y) which is a member of a relation be said to "map" x to y? Is there any reason why that language is not logical or intuitive? Does it conflict with any existing definition of "map"? I think the intended meaning is clear, and the only reason to argue about it is if you are trying to teach strict adherence to definitions.

Comment: @user21820, [re](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25955/students-confusing-object-types-in-introductory-proofs-class#comment66978_25955), while I am broadly sympathetic to this view, I think every comment about the *only* way to do something (especially something teaching related) is almost certain to admit counterexamples.  Trying another approach and having it fail doesn't mean it can't work!  For that matter, trying an approach and having it succeed also doesn't indicate it will succeed again, worse luck for those of us who had a great semester and want to reproduce it ….

Comment: @Acccumulation P is a predicate symbol, frequently misleadingly called a predicate. P(x) is a predicate expression aka predicate in the sense of a written statement, denoting a predicate in the sense of a statement meaning.

Comment: @user253751, [re](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/66992), I think an important point that's easy to miss about your proposed definition is that a reflexive relation really *would* be one that contains all reflexive pairs corresponding to elements of its (say) domain—as opposed, for example, to another common confusion of thinking a linearly independent set is one that consists of linearly independent vectors, which not only is formally wrong but cannot be made correct (short of just replacing it by the correct statement).

Comment: To be clear: sometimes it is important to follow definitions extremely precisely, especially in cases of ambiguity, and that probably should be taught or at least demonstrated a few times, but often it is clear what definition is intended.

Comment: @philipxy "P(x) is a predicate expression aka predicate in the sense of a written statemen" P(x) is not a predicate, unless P is a function from whatever set x is in to the set of predicates.

Comment: @user253751 "Why shouldn't a pair (x,y) which is a member of a relation be said to "map" x to y?" Because that's not what "map" means.

Comment: @Acccumulation and it doesn't mean that because you said it doesn't? or why?

Comment: @Acccumulation "P" is a predicate symbol not a predicate, "P(x)" is a predicate aka predicate expression aka wff, and in standard semantics "P" denotes some set of n-tuples (characterizable as an n-ary boolean function) per some interpretation. Your comments aren't consistent with common use of the terminology. I'm done.

Comment: @LSpice: You are correct that the "only" in my comment cannot be "absolutely only". In my answer posted below I wrote "1% of them will somehow figure out how to do logical reasoning on their own, but 99% of them will never be 100% sure of their own reasoning in the absence of a proper deductive system.". The figure is similar for precision. 1% of students will somehow figure out precisely what you mean **all** the time (if you're not doing something wrong), but 99% of them will often be unsure of what you mean if you are not precise enough. =)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141842/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-students-confusing-object-types-in-introducto).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I personally use terms like "type disagreement" and "type error". This agrees with the notion of types within computer science (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

When I taught linear algebra, I would give students a list of problems of the form "given that $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ are vectors and $a, b,c$ are scalars, identify each of the following formulas as:

- Representing a vector
- Representing a scalar
- Doesn't make sense"

These sorts of problems isolate this specific skill and encourage students to see it as an important skill. This is an unfamiliar type of problem, so you'll need to demonstrate this skill for students in lecture. Keep a list of type errors you see happening to populate these problems.

Comment: If you have this written up as a handout, I'd love to be able to see/borrow/steal it.

Comment: I believe Lay has questions exactly like this. They're tedious at the time, but they really do help a lot. I have often asked the same thing in multivariable calculus classes...I think such questions are in Gulick's book but I'm less confident about that. I might have just made the questions up myself.

Comment: https://trkern.github.io/230homework1.pdf

Comment: It is not only about students. I often catch this type of error (I also call it "type mismatch") when proofreading papers, including my own. Learning a decent programming language that has variable types, not just "var" for everything, so you never know for sure whether 12+34 results in 46 or 1234 (an actual bug in one of my javascript programs that took me an hour to catch), helps a lot. I agree that it is a specific skill that may need separate training.

Comment: @TomKern I was reading your assignment pdf and I disagree with c) DNE: cannot multiply vectors. But the scalar product exists! Being pedantic the one on the left should be transposed, but still vector multiplication does exist.

Answer (score 6):

For me, I use "**type error**" or "**typing error**". I would avoid "type disagreement" because it suggests that you actually have types that disagree. But that's not correct; any expression is only **meaningful** only when it does not have any type error! If there is a type error, it would be more accurate to say that the expression is *meaningless*!

As for how to make sure students do not make this mistake, in my experience typing errors clearly indicate that the students were not taught proper logical reasoning. I have [written before](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/24386/1550) about what I think needs to be taught for students to actually be capable of logical reasoning, and I also think that trying to find a shortcut will be terrible for most students in the long run. 1% of them will somehow figure out how to do logical reasoning on their own, but 99% of them will never be 100% sure of their own reasoning in the absence of a proper deductive system.

Once you have taught a proper deductive system, *all typing errors will completely and permanently vanish*. Also see below for some remarks about the teaching process specific to definitions.

I also want to elaborate on some of my comments. I said:

> Predicates are **not objects** and actually cannot be objects in some foundational systems. They are meta-objects. To truly understand what defining a predicate means, you need to have a solid grasp of basic FOL (e.g. using a Fitch-style system such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820)), and you need to know the distinction between ∃elim and definitorial expansion for new predicate/function-symbols. If you follow the definitorial expansion rule in that linked system, an example would be "Let Q(k) ≡ ¬∃x∈ℤ ( 2^k+5 = 17·x ), for each k∈ℕ.". This is a complete definition of a (fresh) predicate-symbol "Q" (where ℕ,ℤ,+,·,^ are inbuilt or have been defined). You can also see that if you fastidiously follow the rules in that system, you are forced to think about what every object type is, and will never write the kind of nonsense listed in this question.

> I know from experience that the only way to truly impart understanding is to be 100% precise. You must clearly distinguish between **predicates** and **predicate-symbols**. Taking my earlier example, "¬∃x∈ℤ ( 2^[1]+5 = 17·x )" (where the "[1]" is a place-holder for the 1st input parameter) is a predicate, whereas the symbol "Q" in "Let Q(k) ≡ ¬∃x∈ℤ ( 2^k+5 = 17·x ), for each k∈ℕ." is a predicate-symbol. Under "Definitorial expansion" in that linked post you can find the deductive rules supporting definitions, plus a link to [an explanation of why we want definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399880/21820). This motivation tells us that we want to be able to express predicates without having to write it again and again. To support this, we allow defining new predicate-symbols. Make very clear to students this motivation as well as the fact that "Q(E)" can be substituted for the definition of Q with every "[1]" replaced by "E". This is the **true meaning of definitions**.

Regarding the first point, make sure you never call predicates or predicate-symbols "objects"; neither of them are objects. And avoid talking about their "type", because that would be a meta-type. For your own reference (don't tell beginning students about it), Russel's paradox concerns the fact that we can define R(x) ≡ x∉x, for each set x, but in ordinary set theories we cannot have an object that captures this predicate R. That is, we cannot have a set S such that ∀x∈set ( x∈S ⇔ R(x) ), otherwise we would get a contradiction.

Regarding the second point, notice that **if** students truly understand the meaning of definitions (i.e. using symbols to denote a longer expression), **then** automatically they will not write nonsense such as "If P(k) = 2^k+5" when "P" has been declared to denote a predicate. Technically, this problem should never even occur in the first place, because students ought to be taught to correctly use a deductive system **before** even using definitions! In my experience, **none** of my students who learnt my deductive system ever made typing errors...

But if students had been taught in the wrong order, then you can help to get rid of the problem quickly by simply asking them to substitute the "P(k)" for its *exact definition* to show the 'meaning' of what they wrote. They should get something like "If f(k) = 2^k+5 = 2^k+5", and realize why their original is not sensible.

If you really want to comment on types, as per my explanation above, make sure you do **not** say "The type of P is ...". But you **can** say the following:

> Whenever you want to reason about a conditional scenario, you would say "If something, then ...". What can that something be? It can be anything with a **boolean value** (true/false). You cannot say "If elephant, then ...". You can say "If elephants are cute, then ...". You cannot say "If elephants are cute are cute, then ...".

> And if we write "Let P(k) ≡ ( f(k) = 2^k+5 ), for each k∈ℕ.", from then on "P" is a predicate-symbol we can use, and "P(E)" is **boolean** for any expression "E" that is **natural**. Keep in mind that "P" cannot be used by itself; it is simply **ungrammatical** (i.e. syntax error).

> So if we want to reason about the scenario in which "P(k)" is true, then we would say "If P(k), then ...". We cannot say "If P(k) = 2^k+5, then ...". We also cannot say "If 2^k+5, then ...". They are simply **ungrammatical**.

Comment: I have often used "not mathematically grammatical", to avoid scaring off students who feel that they understand less, not more, when the conversation includes the technical meaning of words like "type".

Comment: @LSpice: I agree; I use as little technical terms as possible. Regarding talking about types, I do something like this: "2 and 5 are naturals. If k is a natural, then 2^k is also a natural. Then 2^k+5 is also a natural. If f is a function from naturals to naturals, then f(k) is also a natural. What about ( f(k) = 2^k+5 )? This denotes the result of an equality-test between two objects, which is true or false, so this is a boolean." If I use the word "type", I do so in the standard English sense: "What type of object is 2^k+5?".

Comment: By the way, I find it best to treat booleans as objects too, so that we can uniformly ask "What type of object is ...?" even when the expression denotes an equality-test. This is different from the usual separation of terms and well-formed formulae in formal logic, but I don't see any problem with this more uniform approach for students. (And booleans are on par with 'integers' in most programming languages too.)

Answer (score 2):

These are examples of [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy).

"Let x∈f" instead of "Let x∈B"." This is *totum pro parte* synedoche.  And aspect of the function (the range) is being confused with the function itself. Here, it might help to get your students to think of a function as a verb rather than a noun. $f$ refers to what you *do* to things in $A$, not the things you get after you've done it. This sort of metonymy is very common in language. For instance, "smoke" can mean the process of turning things into a gas, or the gas that results. In math, we can square a number, or say that a number is "square".

"In relations, students often say: "The pairs (1,1),(2,2),(3,3) are reflexive" when we define reflexive as a property of a relation, not a property of individual elements." This is the fallacy of division: a property of the whole is being treated as applying to the parts. This is a common fallacy.

Comment: The example you gave in the original version of your answer is, in my opinion (and in the opinions of several others), needlessly inflammatory and provocative.  The example has been edited out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the three examples are instances of the same error.

> 1. In a proof that a function f:A↦B is onto, a student will say "Let x∈f" instead of "Let x∈B"

Whatever misunderstanding results in this would probably not be cleared up by telling the student that functions are not sets. I think the student will probably add a "typecast" like "Oh, I meant x∈the set of f" which is still just as wrong but now it says it's a set so your complaint is invalid.

I think the actual problem here is there are several sets relating to a particular function (such as its domain, range, codomain, and the set of input/output ordered pairs which is often defined as the function itself) and the student hasn't said which one they're talking about.

> 2. When learning induction, students often define a predicate as being equal to an expression, such as P(x):=2<sup>x</sup>+5

The only immediate problem here is that you're assuming P is a predicate. Now, supposing the student actually does use P as a predicate, I would be very curious to know what they thought it meant. If the student writes $P(x)\lor Q(x)$ what do they think that means? It's the same as writing $(2^x + 5) \lor (3x + 1)$ for example. What does that mean? The error depends on what they think it means.

> 3. In relations, students often say: "The pairs (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
> are reflexive" when we define reflexive as a property of a relation, not a property of individual elements.

I don't see why, in the context of relations, a pair *shouldn't* be defined as reflexive if the two sides are equal. The intention is clear. Your complaint is that it's a non-standard definition in your class. If you are trying to teach strict adherence to definitions, then point that out; otherwise, I see no problem with calling these pairs reflexive as the meaning is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. The lingo, as best as I have witnessed it practiced is:

In philosophy, they can be called [abstract objects (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/).
In mathematics and mathematical philosophy, they are indeed called [mathematical objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object).
In computer science, they are [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) which essentially are a differentiated set used in hierarchies of various sorts to avoid the Russellian paradox at a theoretical level.

As a former high school teacher who used to provide universities and colleges students, I'll make the following statements:

1. The crux of the problem is that there is a difference between [syntax and semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax%E2%80%93semantics_interface) and we do not explicitly teach navigating the dichotomy. Schools overwhelming allow students to process syntax with little grasp of semantics and yet, due to grade inflation and other pressures, consider them educated. To be honest, it's a problem with the system. Students are excellent at regurgitating syntax, but they never quite figure out what it means; I certainly didn't have many insights until I taught math and had to think in depth about it. The real question is what to do about it.
2. If you really want to help students, and you take responsibility for it, then the best way to do it is to design a preliminary of unit of instruction that explicitly teaches the skills. If you're familiar with [Dunning-Kruger's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), which has distinct epistemological overtones with practical pedagogical implications, most students don't even REALIZE they don't know things. What happens in math traditionally, is that mathematics teachers don't realize they have the skill and don't teach it explicitly, and then they promote a series of students who figure it out implicitly who then become teachers never realizing that mastery of mapping semantics onto syntax is an explicit skill. It's a vicious cycle. If you're teaching math, there's a good chance that your intuitions in math are good, and so you also have never explicitly had discussions or lessons about the skill of mapping. You just "get it". That happened to me until I taught in urban education.

What I've said has been said before more pithily. Gauss's quote on teaching is one half [(buried in my MathEdSE answer here)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/24684/18201). Joseph Joubert's witty quote "To teach is to learn twice" is the other.

Here's what you do. You design a diagnostic to specifically test for the sorts of errors in terms of decoding and encoding mathematical syntax and administer it very first day of class. Then, for each category of the mapping this is a function, this is a tuple, this is a real, this is a mapping, this is a relation, ad nauseum, you simply provide a refersher of some sort, and then assign practice. If you do it right, you do it all in natural language. My mid-term and final always had 50 questions in plain English, and my students would wail it wasn't math. And to be fair, they had gone years without anyone actually trying to determine if they could understand the mathematics in depth.

Mathematical comprehension certainly entails a sophistication of syntax, but it is a necessary condition, it is not sufficient. The semantics of math is the backbone of comprehension. Most students can find *c* given a Pythagorean theorem, but can they have a discussion about why the hypotenuse is equal to the positive root of the sum of the square of the legs? The former is plug and chug, the latter is mathematical discourse and sadly, the string of teachers that furnished you your students probably rushed though content to meet district requirements dealing with large batches of irregularly educated students. In the US, at least, mastery in mathematics at the elementary and secondary levels isn't a thing except for the gifted.

If that's too much work for you, then that is what it is. But if you're contemporary in your pedagogy, you can easily use software to automate the grading and tracking, and could easily make it a regular feature of your instruction. I would give my midterm and final questions in natural language at the start of the semester to be worked on and reflected upon, and students would still struggle with answering the questions. The lengths you go to bend over backwards to teach helps determine whether you shake out as a mathematician just teaching math or are actually a math educator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $f: A \to B$ from the start, it might be more instructive to formally write $\forall x: [x \in A \implies f(x) \in B]$. Then you cannot infer from this that $x \in f$. This, of course, would require some familiarity with basic predicate logic.